# How can a C++ application use more Heap than RSS Memory?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

I have a C++ executable for a multithreads application which involves the opening of UDP ports.

I'm measuring the memory usage of this application using different tools.

From my understanding of Linux memory usage, `RSS = Heap + Stack + Shared + CodeSize`.

However, now I think that the equation is wrong, because my application has:

- Peak Heap usage: 40Mb
- Peak RSS: 30Mb

I measured the numbers with different tools (`valgrind`, `heaptrack`, `top`..) so I can say that they are correct.

How can it be possible?
What are the causes and the consequences of this situation?

Thanks

Comment: If I well understand RSS, this is the amout of RAM used at a certain point of time. So, this only means that all the address space of your program is not loaded all in RAM. There's surely some part of it on the swap

Comment: [Wiki page for RSS explains this quite well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size). RSS is how much of your memory is actually in RAM. There are many reasons why memory allocated by your program may not be in RAM yet or anymore.

Comment: It is all about the [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Terminology) i.e. some pages are on swapping partition when peek period, since they are more likely not used by the code (cold zone) and kernel understanding this and moving it from RAM to HDD.

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov The `SWAP` column from `top` always shows `0` during my application execution.

Comment: Memory allocated but not yet used will not yet have main memory assigned. If you allocate a huge array, you may not see an increase in RSS. If you access the first and last element in the array, you may only see the pages that contain the first and last elements, and nothing between, in RSS.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok so, if I `malloc` a 100Kb array, but then I always access only the same 10Kb, will the RSS only show 10Kb?
And what about the full 100Kb size, is it counted in both Heap and VSZ?

Comment: @user4581301 Ok, I tested with a simple program and it is exactly like this: memory which is allocated, but not initialized will be counted in the Heap and in the VSZ, while not being part of the RSS.
You can answer the question so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user4581301 pointed out in the comments, there was a problem in my idea of RSS.

`HEAP = DynamicMemoryAllocated`

`RSS = DynamicMemoryInitialized + Stack + Shared + CodeSize`

So it is not true that all the heap size is contained in the RSS, but only the part of it which has been initialized.

If you allocate space for a 10Mb array, this is HEAP.
If you start initializing it, then the initialized parts will be counted as RSS.

Answer (score 0):

RSS is the *Resident* Set Size.

Not all the heap is necessarily resident - it may be swapped out, for example.

However, the *Virtual* memory usage will include all of the heap (both resident and non-resident portions).